# HTML/CSS div positioning

Tags: html, css

I have 3 scripts in my HTML file and I'm having trouble with positioning.

[image]

As you can see my vertical gauge is on top on my second circular gauge.
I tried multiple positioning options but I'm not able to fix this.
How can I make my vertical gauge be on the right side of my first circular gauge?

This is how my code looks at the moment.

```
<body>
    <div id="containerTno" style="height:300px;width:800px;margin:0px;position:static">
        <div id="circularGaugeContainer" style="height:300px;width:300px;position:relative"></div>
        <div id="linearGaugeContainer" style="height:300px;width:300px;position:relative"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="circularGaugeContainer2" style="height:300px;width:300px;margin:0px; position:static"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: try assigning them width like for first container as 60% and container two as 35%, with display: inline-block and float:left/right

Comment: could you provide your code in fiddle?

Comment: please give proper heading, the topic is related to html/css positioning not related to scripts

Comment: @RaunakKathuria that worked! Can you answer that so I can accept as correct answer? It might help other people!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For expected layout try assigning following css for the first container as

```
width:60%
```

and second container as

```
width: 30-40%; float: right;
```

and display as

```
display: inline-block
```

for both the container

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you use this two lines instead it should work

```
<div id="circularGaugeContainer" style="height:300px;width:300px; float: left;"></div>
<div id="linearGaugeContainer" style="height:300px;width:300px; float: right;"></div>
```

I didn't use JFiddler but I'm quite sure this works. let us know its an easy fix